# How to use Matlab/Octave regexprep (regular expression replace) to add suffix to file name before extension

Tags: regex, matlab, octave, filenames, suffix

Say I have this Matlab or Octave char variable:

```
>> filename = 'my.file.ext'
```

I want a regexprep command that adds a suffix, say '_old', to the file name before the extension, transforming it into 'my.file_old.ext'.

The following replaces all dots with '_old.':

```
>> regexprep(filename, '\.', '_old.')
ans =
    'my_old.file_old.ext'
```

What is a regexprep command that prepends '_old' only to the last dot? (Ideally, if there is no dot (no extension), append '_old' at the very end.)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
regexprep(filename, '^(?:(.*)(\.)|(.*))', '$3$1_old$2')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E6b9oZ/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(.*)(\.)|(.*))` - a non-capturing group matching either of the two alternatives:

  - `(.*)(\.)` - Group 1 (`$1` backreference refers to the value of the group): any zero or more chars as many as possible and then Group 2 (`$2`): a dot
  - `|` - or
  - `(.*)` - Group 3 (`$3`): any zero or more chars as many as possible

If an alternative is not matched, the backreference to the capturing group is an empty string. Thus, if `(.*)(\.)` matches, the replacement is Group 1 + `_old` + Group 2 value. Else, it is Group 3 + `_old` (just appending at the end).

Comment: Great! Thank you, Wiktor.

Comment: Sorry, Wiktor, for some reason it works in Octave:

    >> regexprep('my.file.ext', '^(?:(.*)(\.)|(.*))', '$3$1_old$2')
    ans = my.file_old.ext

but in Matlab (9.6.0.1072779 (R2019a)) it does not:

    >> regexprep('my.file.ext', '^(?:(.*)(\.)|(.*))', '$3$1_old$2')
    ans =
        '$3$1_old$2ext'

Any idea why?

Comment: @FelipeJiménez No idea why, the replacement syntax is the same.

Comment: @wiktor.stribizew Thank you, I posted the Q to MathWork's "Matlab Answers" and will bring feedback here in case you're interested.

Comment: You can see answer by Walter Roberson here:
https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/577600-how-to-correct-unexpected-behavior-of-regexprep
(Hope it is ok to link to there.)

Comment: @FelipeJiménez If the explanation is correct you may simply change the non-capturing group with a capturing one and increment the backreferences, `regexprep(filename, '^((.*)(\.)|(.*))', '$4$2_old$3')`

Comment: No, the explanation seems not ok, since your last command again works in Octave but not in Matlab (where the result is '$4$2_old$3ext').

Answer (score 4):

If doing it without regular expressions is an option, you can use [`fileparts`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html) as follows:

```
filename  = 'my.file.ext';
suffix = '_old';
[p, n, e] = fileparts(filename); % path, file, extension; each possibly empty
result = [p, n, suffix, e];
```

[Example](https://tio.run/##vY5JCgMhEEX3nqI2wQSkLyA5SQjBdEpacKKrOujpbc2wyj7LP/D@TzObJ7ZGm7WuwBnkLfmH1EJY5zGagDDMUKehJywsxSUriArw2pPhZrMyHb/9k4YDZMOLeoW9VxgjuRQ1oJkXyInI3X0FDJmrWJE2zx31wb6fDPzPhyH/N9/aDg) in Octave.

Comment: Thank you Luis, I know I could use fileparts, but wanted to know how to use regexprep.

Comment: I see. Glad you found your answer!